# Windows 7, Lenovo Keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Have just purchased a Lenovo Keyboard with fingerprint reader, which driver do I need and where do I get it, using Windows 7

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How can I use my IBM/Lenovo keyboard fingerprint reader on a non-lenovo Windows 7 PC?](http://superuser.com/q/909200/16858)

Answer (score 3):

Did it not come with a disk?  Lenovo is pretty good about that.

That said, if you'd take the time to Google "lenovo usb keyboard with fingerprint reader" the first hit that comes back is [their product page](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-58714) (I am assuming this is what you have since I think they're only shipping the one) which has a link at the bottom to ["Software and device drivers"](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-62215.html).

Google is your friend - learn to help yourself and you'd be amazed how productive you can be. ;)